Bounding a ratio between sum of the powers of a probability distribution
I have a probability distribution $p$ with $n$ possible outcomes and I need to bound the following ratio. I want to find the smallest $c$ such that the following holds:
$$
\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}p_i^{2k-1}}{(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}p_i^k)^2} \leq c
$$
I assume $k$ is a constant integer greater than $1$ but $n$ is not a constant. Is there a constant $c$ such that the above holds? Or can it become arbitrarily big in terms of $n$?
I tried the extreme cases where $p$ is the uniform distribution or the case where some $p_i$ is 1. For both of these extremes, we have $c = 1$. However, I also found some cases where $c > 1$, but I could not make this ratio arbitrarily big.

$0 \le p_i \le 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^np_i = 1$ hold. Are there any constraints on $k$?

I just assume $k$ is a constant integer greater than 1. I will add this to the statement.
